# What url should I use

Tags: forms

I'm using this to search Google from my website:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.nl/search">
```

What url should I use to search images and videos? I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search Images:
http://www.google.nl/imghp?hl=nl&tab=ni

To search Video:
http://video.google.nl/?hl=nl&tab=wv

Comment: It doesn't work..If I fill in a search query and post I get the google video site pre-filled with my query but no results

Comment: images I use: `http://images.google.nl/images?q=` For video I use: `http://video.google.nl/videosearch?hl=nl&q=`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could just use the same URLs that show up after searching on Images/Videos. Here's the result for the string "cookies":

http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=570&q=cookies&gbv=2&oq=cookies&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1208l1498l0l1658l4l2l0l0l0l0l143l220l1.1l2l0

After messing around with the query parameters a bit, I was able to eliminate everything except the requirements for an image search:

http://www.google.com/search?q=cookies&tbm=isch

Looks as though &tbm needs to be passed in, and in your case could be a hidden input in HTML:

Change it to this for videos:

Comment: images I use: `http://images.google.nl/images?q=` For video I use: `http://video.google.nl/videosearch?hl=nl&q=`

Answer (score 0):

To search Images --- http://www.google.com/imghp

To search Videos --- http://video.google.com/?hl=en&tab=iv

But to integrate more efficiently in application better to use.

[JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)

The JSON/Atom Custom Search API lets you develop websites and programs to retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically. With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get search results in either JSON or Atom format

Comment: If you are using your own javascript for searching images and videos more customization is required in code having drawbacks.